# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in LINE 44

Tags: php, xml, request, response

I got Error in Line $x = $x->firstChild->textContent; the display is okay but the notice error display, how to get rid of this notice error? I just got this code from the rss feeds. I don't know exactly what happen.

```
<?php

$Universal_Style = "p";   // replace that by span class="" to custom
$Universal_Date_Font = "size='-1'";

$Universal_FeedArray = array();

$Universal_AtomChannelTags = array("title","link","subTitle","updated");
$Universal_AtomItemTags = array("title","link","summary","pubDate");

$Universal_RssChannelTags = array("title","link","description","lastBuildDate");
$Universal_RssItemTags = array("title","link","description","pubDate");

$Universal_Translation = array("title"=>"title", 
  "link"=>"link",
  "description"=>"description",
  "subTitle"=>"description",
  "summary"=>"description",
  "lastBuildDate"=>"updated",
  "pubDate"=>"updated");

$Universal_Doc = false;


/**
 *  Read the content of a tag
 *  Input: 
 *  - element: the node
 *  - tag: the name of the tag
 *  Ouput:
 *  - the content
 */       

function getTag($element, $tag)
{
  $x = $element->getElementsByTagName($tag);
  if($x->length == 0)
  {
    return false;
  }  
  $x = $x->item(0);
  $x = $x->firstChild->textContent;
  return $x;
}

?>
```

Comment: Where the function getTag is called?

Comment: Sounds like `$x->item(0)` doesn't have any children, so `$x->firstChild` returns null.